# Only execute CompletableFuture callback when status of result is completed

Tags: java, zendesk-api

I am currently working with the Zendesk API and creating users. I am using the CompletableFuture framework to perform the operation of creating the users and then adding a callback to handle the result. However, the result of the createUsers() method is a JobStatus object that could have the status of "queued", "completed", "working". What I would like is for the callback to be executed only when the status is "completed". Is this possible? If the status is "queued", I want it to keep waiting until the result is "completed".

For this example, assume that the list contains a set of users to be created.

```
public void createEndUsers(Zendesk zd, List<User> usersToBeCreated){
    final static CompletableFuture<JobStatus<User>> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();

    promise.supplyAsync(() -> {
            JobStatus<User> js = zd.createUsers(usersToBeCreated);
            return js;
        }).thenAccept(Testing::updateDB);
}

public void updateDB(JobStatus<User> resultObject){
    //perform various operations on the JobStatus object
}
```

Comment: How would you have done it if you didn't have CompletableFuture?  There is no magic here, you will need to poll JobStatus for its state or createUsers should be rewritten to not return an intermediate object.

Comment: createUsers cannot be rewritten as it is a part of the Zendesk API and I do not want to meddle with that. 

As for the rest, I could simply do a loop that checks the Zendesk API and updates the status of the JobStatus object and keeps doing that until the status is "completed", but I was hoping there was a more elegant way of doing a callback on certain conditions.

Comment: There's an API call that creates a single user.  It seems to return only when the job is complete.  It seems that you could just call multiple of these in parallel until you've created all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be using the code:

```
private static final int DELAY = 100;
public void createEndUsers(Zendesk zd, List<User> usersToBeCreated){
    final CompletableFuture<JobStatus<User>> promise = new CompletableFuture<>();

    promise.supplyAsync(() -> {
        JobStatus<User> js = zd.createUsers(usersToBeCreated);
        JobStatus.JobStatusEnum jsStatus = js.getStatus();

        while (jsStatus == JobStatus.JobStatusEnum.working || jsStatus == JobStatus.JobStatusEnum.queued){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted exception occurred while sleeping until the next attempt of retrieving the job status for the job " + js.getId(), e);
            }
            js =  zd.getJobStatus(js);
            jsStatus =js.getStatus();
        }
        return js;
    }).thenAccept(Testing::updateDB);
}

public static void updateDB(JobStatus<User> resultObject){
    //perform various operations on the JobStatus object
}
```

The sleeping operation is definitely not ideal, but via Zendesk API you can only check for the job status completion status.